# In Linux, how do I dlopen a shared object stored uncompressed inside another file?

Tags: linux, dlopen

A few years ago I heard Google had a patch to dlopen a shared object stored inside another file at a non-zero offset, or mmap'd, instead of sitting in its own standalone file. Did that ever land? What's the API for loading these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did that ever land in Linux mainline?

1. This has *nothing* to do with Linux mainline: GLIBC is a completely separate project from Linux kernel (which is what people usually call "Linux mainline").
2. No; we still carry it as a local patch. It works with restrictions, which make it somewhat unsuitable for upstream.

> What's the API for loading these objects?

```
void *dlopen_with_offset(const char *name, off_t offset, int flags);
```

Comment: Is the patch public?

Answer (score 0):

There is a long-standing but incomplete request for feature enhancement to implement this in glibc, discussion at https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11767

Here's someone's proof of concept implementation. https://github.com/m1m1x/memdlopen